# How to efficiently process log file using C implementation

Tags: c, logging, sed, awk

I want to process a log file(using C) in which the data are separated by double colons "::". I suppose tools like `awk` and `sed` will be quite efficient to do this. But is it possible that awk output values can pass to my C variable?
For example, one log info is like this:

```
a::b::c::d
```

and I have a `struct` consists of 4 `int` elements. How to save the 4 parts into the struct elements?
I've thought of using `strtok` libary call as another way, but before calling it, I have to sort out the suitable lines from a whole bunch of log information, and that makes me think more about the `sed` or `grep`.
Thank you for your help. If you have better choices, that will be very kind of you to share it.

update: I forgot to emphasize that everything mentioned above is done in **runtime** including "sort out the matched lines according to a given value", and process them, then store the value. `scanf` is fine, but what if there is `string` value with spaces inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a mixture of tools. For example, let's say your log file is in the file `log.out`.

Then you can use `grep` to select the lines you are interested in:

```
grep "^-\?[0-9]\+::-\?[0-9]\+::-\?[0-9]\+::-\?[0-9]\+$" log.out
```

You could either store it as another file, *or* directly give it to your program:

```
grep ... | ./analyze_data
```

Assuming your program is named `analyze_data`. In the source of the program, you simply read from `stdin` and store the values you want:

```
scanf("%d::%d::%d::%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

Of course with proper error checking.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what if I need to do it in runtime and the logfile lines contain description strings with space inside?

Comment: If the log file is the output of another program, you can easily pipe it in to `grep`. But if you really want to do all in C, I can help you. However, from the comment on another answer I saw that you said: `For string values with spaces inside, scanf can not work properly`. So how are these strings delimited? With `::`?

Comment: Yes, just assuming that string value will not contain any double colons. To make it precise, I have two functions(`writelog` and `readlog`) operating on one log file. As for `writelog` I can simply `open` it and append logs into the file. But for `readlog`, I'm confused about how should I sort out the `n` lines that match, separate the elements line by line, and store them into `n` structures respectively. Right now I'm using `popen` and pass command `grep '<expr>' logfile` to it, then `getline` one line each time, but stuck on how to separate the elements. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: The best way I'd say is to open the log file and read line by line. Then once you have fully read a line, try to see if it matches the pattern you are looking for. You can use `strstr` to find the locations of `::`s inside the line (and if it failed, then you ignore the line). The 4 strings are then easily subtracted from the indices of the `::`s you found.

Comment: That's quite a good choice! One question, isn't it more efficient to just process the matched lines, as the logfile will getting bigger and bigger. Another question, to extend the topic, using `awk` is quite simple to separate a line into `$1`, `$2`, etc. Is there a way I can use it inside a C program and pass those `$1`s into the C variables?

Comment: @leowang, whatever you use to filter the lines (e.g. `grep`) would read the lines, match and choose to keep or throw away. So it wouldn't make much difference if _you_ do it, or `grep` does it. It's the same algorithm. I'm not sure if you can use `awk` in any way except with `popen`. By the way, how do you use `awk` to separate the records? Does `awk` take `::` as delimiter? If `:` could never happen in the string, you can still use `scanf`, but instead of `%s`, use `%[^:]`. This reads anything (including space) until it reaches a `:`.

Comment: That's it! I haven't used patterns like `%[^:]` in `scanf` before. I will have a try. Thanks again for all the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stay away from `strtok` until you really need it. This can be done with `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d::%d::%d::%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

And, of the three tools `sed`, `awk` and `grep`, it really depends on the details of "sort out the suitable lines". `grep` is fine for detecting a value. `awk` and `sed` are much more powerful tools, but they require much more investment in time to learn (they are both Turing-Complete programming languages).

Comment: `grep` can do the work. I only need to sort out the lines containing the given value. And `awk` can separate the input into 4 parts(`$1`, `$2`...). The thing annoying me is that I need to do it in runtime, so can I pass the `$1` to `$4` to self-defined variables? And forget about the `int`. For string values with spaces inside, `scanf` can not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a pointer "s" to struct  with 4 integer fields and an opened FILE "logfile":

```
    res = fscanf(logfile, "%d::%d::%d::%d", &s->field0, &s->field1, &s->field2, &s->field3);
```

Comment: Nice. I forgot it was a struct. +1

Comment: But there are quite a lot of lines like this inside the logfile